# How to change Seller name in Appstore

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I want to change Seller name in Appstore. My developer account created as company/organization.
The easiest way to change is to contact itunesconnect@apple.com. What are the details I need to send to Apple contact.

Comment: http://www.brynbodayle.com/changing-app-store-seller-name/

Comment: Have you got this fixed, and how? What was the procedure to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the new name is permissible: Since you said it was initially registered as a company, note that the new name must match your legal entity. In Apple's words:

> We do not accept DBAs, Fictitious Businesses, Trade names, or branches. The legal entity name will appear as the “seller” for apps you distribute on the App Store and Mac App Store.

Also, as per [this page](https://developer.apple.com/support/enrollment/), you will need a DUNS number to prove the existance of this entity, and legal authority over it.

With that in mind, [Contact Apple Developer Support](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) (not iTunes Connect), with the DUNS number to prove the existance of this entity.

Comment: @user2931321 Glad I could help!